# Using temp table with exec @sql in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure and part of them as below:
@DRange is a incoming varchar value

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * into #tmpA from TableA where create_date >= getDate - ' + @DRange + '' and is_enabled = 1'

exec (@sql)

select * from #tmpA
```

The problem is when I execute the stored procedure, an error message occurs:
Cannot find the object "#tmpA" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Is it not possible to use temp table and execute it or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL? Can't you have a normal query `select * into #tmpA from TableA where create_date >= getDate - @DRange and is_enabled = 1` ? Covert @DRange into different type if needed

Comment: Because I will need to combine the other parameter, such as database name into the query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#tmpA` is created in a different scope, so is not visible outside of the dynamic SQL. You can just make the ultimate `SELECT` a part of the dynamic SQL. Also a couple of other things:

- [Always use the schema prefix when creating/referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [Always use `sp_executesql` for dynamic SQL](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql); in this case it allows you to parameterize the `@DRange` value and avoid SQL injection risks.
- Always prefix Unicode strings with `N` - Unicode is required for `sp_executesql` but if you get lazy about this in other areas of your code it can also lead to painful implicit conversions.

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'select * into #tmpA from dbo.TableA 
    where create_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -@DRange, GETDATE())
    AND is_enabled = 1; SELECT * FROM #tmpA';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@DRange INT', @DRange;
```

Of course if all you're doing is selecting, I have a hard time understanding why this is dynamic SQL in the first place. I assume your query (or what you later do with the temp table) is more complicated than this - if so, don't dumb it down for us. Telling us your whole problem will prevent a lot of back and forth, as the additional details could change the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have use ##tmpA instead of #tmp and the problem has solved.

Comment: @WilliamTang no, it hasn't. Do you know what ##tmpA does? This creates a GLOBAL temp table. Guess what happens when two people run this stored procedure at the same time (regardless of what your date range or database parameters are).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd do.

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'select * from TableA where create_date >= getDate - ' + @DRange + '' and is_enabled = 1'

Select * Into #tmpA from TableA where create_date = '01/01/1000' -- to create a blank table

insert into #tmpA

exec (@sql)

select * from #tmpA
```