# Dynamic SQL Result INTO #Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, dynamic-sql

I have to Execute a dynamic SQL `SELECT` Query And put Results into a `#TempTable`.

```
DECLARE @StateId CHAR(3)='StateID';  
DECLARE @DeptId CHAR(15)='DeptID';  
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)='Select Columns With Joins Passed From Front End'  
DECLARE @Where VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @FinalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)='';  
SET @Where='Some Where Condition';  
SET @FinalQuery='SELECT '+@Query+' '+@Where+''  
EXEC(@FinalQuery) -- Want To INSERT THIS Result IN SOME `#TempTable` 
                  -- SO that I can perform Some Operations On `#TempTable`
```

ALSO No Of columns returned From Dynamic SQL `SELECT` Are Dynamic.

Thanks,

Comment: And where are you facing difficulties?

Comment: How to Insert dynamic `SELECT` query result into `#TempTable`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using temp table with exec @sql in stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555502/using-temp-table-with-exec-sql-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: @downvoter..care to comment plz?

Answer (score 4):

try the below example

```
DECLARE @StateId CHAR(3)='StateID';  
DECLARE @DeptId CHAR(15)='DeptID';  
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)='*'  -- here you pass your query
DECLARE @Where VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @FinalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)='';  
SET @Where='from tablename where condition';  
SET @FinalQuery='SELECT '+@Query+' INTO #temptablename '+@Where;
EXEC(@FinalQuery)
```

Note
:If you need to use temtable after sp execution then use ## rather than # then we can access it or we can use persistent temporary table

Comment: And how do you access #tempTableName afterwards? It's existance is only during the execution of the dyanmic query, so you can't access it afterwards.

Comment: @Arunprasanth KV, I have already Tried This,..but `#TempTable` will not be accessible afterwards.

Comment: yes i agree with you . it is not accesable afterwords if you want to do something like that then use  persistent temporary table

Comment: or use ## rather than #

Comment: yup...i agree. what is your real problem ?

Comment: A temporary table created within a Stored Procedure is dropped when the Stored Procedure ends, so if you want something like your requirement then use global temtable otherwise you can't do that.

Comment: Wiil it cause problems when procedure is executed concurrently by many users?

Comment: it will be perminent until reboot i mean persistant

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your query statements is correctly.
Try this in your stored procedure and check the output results ( copy the result and execute it)

```
....
SET @FinalQuery='SELECT '+@Query+' '+@Where+'    
PRINT(@FinalQuery)
....
```

You can use the **SQL Profiler** tool to debug

Comment: Not really a solution.

Comment: My Dynamic Query In Correct And Executes Successfully..But I Want to Insert The Dynamic Query Result Into Some `#TempTable`

Comment: Try this one : INSERT INTO #TempTable EXEC(@FinalQuery)
Make sure the number of columns are the same

Comment: @trungtin1710 #TempTable needs to be declared/created before.

Comment: @trungtin1710 no of columns in `Select` are dynamic as mentioned in Qus.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I agreed with you. This assumes he have already created before

Comment: @trungtin1710 Then, that would no longer be a temporary table, but an actual table (which, I think, kind of beats the OP's point)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
First create the temp table which you need for further calculation.

CREATE  TABLE #TEMP
    (
    STATEID INT,
    DEPTID INT
    )

```
DECLARE @STATEID CHAR(10)='STATEID';  
DECLARE @DEPTID CHAR(15)='DEPTID';  
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)='INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE 
                             SELECT COLUMNS WITH JOINS PASSED FROM FRONT END'  
DECLARE @WHERE VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @FINALQUERY VARCHAR(MAX)=''  
SET @WHERE='SOME WHERE CONDITION'

SET @FINALQUERY=+@QUERY+' '+@WHERE+''  -- REMOVED SELECT 
EXEC(@FINALQUERY)
```