# Using Temp Table created by using dynamic query in Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql, temp-tables

I have a dynamic query which gets certain records from another database (database server and database name are variables, hence used dynamic query).

Below is the query

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(1000)      
set @SQLString='
select distinct(select distinct
(
select * from
(
    ------- Inner query (It is more complex than this)

    select lAccountId, sAccountName 
    from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccDetails  
    where lAccountId = 10  
    union  
    select lAccountId, sAccountName 
    from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccHistoryDetails  
    where lAccountId = 10 
) A
    for xml raw(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts''), ELEMENTS 
)) as AccXmlValue,
lAccountId as AccountId      
into       
 #tmpAccDetails
from       
 AccountDetails      
where       
 AccountDetails.laccountID in (''10,11'')'     

EXECUTE (@SQLString)    

----- This is the final SQL statement (It is more complex than this)

select * from 
MainAccTable M
inner join #tmpAccDetails tmp on M.lAccountId = tmp.AccountId
```

I want to use the `#tmpAccDetails` in join with `MainAccTable`.

1. How can I achieve this, as the temp table will not be in scope outside the dynamic SQL?
2. Using Global Temp table solves this, but will it be a good idea to use it in this scenario?

My question is similar to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555502/using-temp-table-with-exec-sql-in-stored-procedure) here, except for the fact that I will have to use the `#tmpAccDetails` table in join, rather than selecting the data from this at one go.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have myself solved the question and posting the answer here, so that others may benefit from the same.

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)      
set @SQLString='
select distinct(select distinct
(
select * from
(
------- Inner query (It is more complex than this)

select lAccountId, sAccountName 
from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccDetails  
where lAccountId = 10  
union  
select lAccountId, sAccountName 
from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccHistoryDetails  
where lAccountId = 10 
) A
for xml raw(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts''), ELEMENTS 
)) as AccXmlValue,
lAccountId as AccountId      
from       
 '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccountDetails     
where       
 laccountID in (''10,11'')' 

---- Create temp table here
CREATE TABLE #tmpAccDetails 
(
AccXmlValue NVarchar(max),
AccountId int 
);

---- Insert into temp table here
INSERT INTO #tmpAccDetails EXECUTE (@SQLString)

---- Select from temp table here
Select * from 
MainAccTable M
inner join #tmpAccDetails tmp on M.lAccountId = tmp.AccountId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be OK if you create the temp table first....

Eg....

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(1000)      

CREATE TABLE #tmpAccDetails
(lAccountId int, 
 sAccountName  NVArchar(100)
);


set @SQLString='
select distinct(select distinct
(
select * from
(
    ------- Inner query (It is more complex than this)

    select lAccountId, sAccountName 
    from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccDetails  
    where lAccountId = 10  
    union  
    select lAccountId, sAccountName 
    from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccHistoryDetails  
    where lAccountId = 10 
) A
    for xml raw(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts''), ELEMENTS 
)) as AccXmlValue,
lAccountId as AccountId      
into       
 #tmpAccDetails
from       
 AccountDetails      
where       
 AccountDetails.laccountID in (''10,11'')'     

EXECUTE (@SQLString)    

Select * from 
MainAccTable M
inner join #tmpAccDetails tmp on M.lAccountId = tmp.AccountId
```

Comment: No, this does not work. The data does not get inserted into the temp table this way.

Comment: It does not give any error, it returns empty result.

Comment: Suggesting it is inserting somewhere or the dynamic sql is not returning rows. You have got my curiosity on this one........I'm going to experiment

Comment: The temp table goes out of scope after the dynamic query, I guess. Do you know any other way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have any linked servers sso I cannot try.
Wierd that it does out of scope as it is created in the same batch.
I'll be watching how yuou get on.

Good luck


 
Before I go......What about trying to prefix the temp table with the SERVER & Database names.....and using the prefixes when ever you create or select from the table. CREATE TABLE SERVERNAME.TempDB.#tmpAccDetails (lAccountId int, sAccountName NVArchar(100) );

Comment: I have solved the question myself and posted the answer. +1 for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of the statements, like this:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(1000)   

set @SQLString='
select distinct(select distinct
(
select * from
(
    ------- Inner query (It is more complex than this)

    select lAccountId, sAccountName 
    from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccDetails  
    where lAccountId = 10  
    union  
    select lAccountId, sAccountName 
    from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccHistoryDetails  
    where lAccountId = 10 
) A
    for xml raw(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts''), ELEMENTS 
)) as AccXmlValue,
lAccountId as AccountId      
into       
 #tmpAccDetails
from       
 AccountDetails      
where       
 AccountDetails.laccountID in (''10,11'')'     


CREATE TABLE #tmpAccDetails
(lAccountId int, 
 sAccountName  NVArchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO #tmpAccDetails
EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL    

Select * from 
MainAccTable M
inner join #tmpAccDetails tmp on M.lAccountId = tmp.AccountId
```

Comment: What is `@sSQL` here?

Comment: @ser_nicky It works if I run this as a query, does not work if it is put inside a stored procedure.

Comment: @Senjuti Mahapatra - Oh, you didn't mention that this portion of code should be run within the stored procedure. Since you haven't provided SP details, please take a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4e7366e9-7b16-4ad2-9616-816ccbffdf63/executing-stored-procedure-with-input-parameters-using-spexecutesql?forum=transactsql

Comment: @ser_nicky: Your answer was almost correct and helped me to solve my question. I have solved the question myself and posted the answer. +1 for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN  
    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(1000)      

      CREATE TABLE #tmpAccDetails
      (lAccountId int, 
       sAccountName  NVArchar(100)
      );


      set @SQLString=' INSERT INTO  #tmpAccDetails

      select distinct(select distinct
      (
      select * from
      (
          ------- Inner query (It is more complex than this)

          select lAccountId, sAccountName 
          from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccDetails  
          where lAccountId = 10  
          union  
          select lAccountId, sAccountName 
          from '+@DatabaseServer+'.'+@DatabaseName+'.dbo.AccHistoryDetails  
          where lAccountId = 10 
      ) A
          for xml raw(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts''), ELEMENTS 
      )) as AccXmlValue,
      lAccountId as AccountId      
      into       
       #tmpAccDetails
      from       
       AccountDetails      
      where       
       AccountDetails.laccountID in (''10,11'')'     

      EXECUTE (@SQLString)    

      Select * from 
      MainAccTable M
      inner join #tmpAccDetails tmp on M.lAccountId = tmp.AccountId 


      RollBAck Tran
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered "OPENDATASOURCE" to access data from another database ?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms179856.aspx

You can join tables from different databases with this method

```
    SELECT *
    FROM MainAccTable M
    INNER JOIN OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLOLEDB', 'Data Source=@myInstance;User ID=@myUserName;Password=@myPassword).XXX.dbo.AccountId AS tmp 
ON tmp.AccountId = M.lAccountId
```